# How to select a default option in ng2 using child component

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-forms, angular-ngselect

I'm building an app where I built an input component that can adapt to be and text input, a select, text area, etc...

So I create a model for that, where I send all the information it needs so the component can adapt to what I need. I'm also using formCOntrol and not ngModel for the forms (after reading some pages that came up to be the best option)

The issue I have is that I cannot preselect a value for the ng-select (previously I was using select component and it was sowrking fine.

So in the create form, I have like 20 inputs of different types and everything is fine... The issue appears when I try to do the Edit action of something, as I need to have all the inputs prepopulated with the original value. For all the components is ok, as I'm sharing the formControlName with the model of the entity I want to update, but for the ng2-select I get the following error:

```
ERROR TypeError: selectedItems.map is not a function
```

I googled for the possibles solutions but none works for me.. Maybe as I'm using a ng-select inside another component....

So here is my code.
This is the route:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.supplierService.get(this.item.id).subscribe( (response : JsonResponse)=> {
      if(response.success){
        this.item = response.data;
        this.item.logo = this.supplierService.getImage(this.item);
        this.getState();

      }
  else{
    this.error = response.code;
  }
});
```

}
As you can see, first I get the item (object to edit). Then I get the states (items that will be shown as option in the ng-select

And after I get the states, I create the formControl:

```
this.form = new FormGroup({
                name: new FormControl(this.item.name,Validators.required),
                last_name: new FormControl(this.item.last_name, Validators.required),
                fantasy_name: new FormControl(this.item.fantasy_name, Validators.required),
                real_name: new FormControl(this.item.real_name, Validators.required),
                state: new FormControl(this.item.state ? this.item.state : '', Validators.required),
                city: new FormControl(this.item.city ? this.item.city : '', Validators.required),
                phone: new FormControl(this.item.phone),
                fax: new FormControl(this.item.fax),
                discount: new FormControl(this.item.discount),
                address: new FormControl(this.item.address),
                apartment: new FormControl(this.item.apartment),
                cuit: new FormControl(this.item.cuit, Validators.required),
                email: new FormControl(this.item.email, Validators.required),
                floor: new FormControl(this.item.floor),
                mobile_phone : new FormControl(this.item.mobile_phone)
              });
```

Finally, I create the component for each input, here you have the state example:

```
let state : InputForm = new InputForm();
    state.setSelect("state", 'COMPONENT.COMMON.STATE', this.states, 6);
    this.formElement.elements.push(state);
```

There I set that this component will be a select, I the first param is the name in the formControlName (in this way, it knows which is the formCOntrolName so It can set this value as default or assign the new one on submit. Then, the label, and then the list of items to show. (The last param is the size of the input).

And this is the template for my component corresponding to select:

```
<ng-select *ngIf="element.type == 'select' && (element.items && element.items.length > 0)" (typed)="typed(element.id, $event)" formControlName="{{element.id}}" [allowClear]="true" [items]="element.items" (selected)="change(element.id, $event)" id="{{element.id}}" (removed)="removed($event)" (typed)="typed($event)" placeholder="{{element.placeholder | translate}}"></ng-select>
```

I tried with [active], [data], [initData] but nothing works. I always get the error

```
ERROR TypeError: selectedItems.map is not a function
```

I dont't know if I should be assigning the default value in other way.The error is in line

```
this._active = selectedItems.map(function (item)
```

And in that case, the selectedItems is State type (my custom type)I don't know if I should do a transformation before that. The type has id and text value.

In summary, the error is just in "edit" actions.. I mean, when the element has a value preselected, if not it works fine.

I'm using angular 4.3.3

See the below image from the line that is failing:

[image]

There you can see that the object is sent, and also the map function is undefined.

Comment: The error is saying that selectedItems isn't an array or is undefined. before the line `this._active = selectedItems.map(function (item)...` if you output console.log(selectedItems) what do you see?

Comment: @inspired I added the image so you can see what selectedItems is

Comment: ah i see. Its an object not an array. Object doesn't have the map method. Can you show me where you are defining selectedItems?

Comment: SelectedItems is not defined by me, is in the select.js.. But you make me realized that I need to convert this                 state: new FormControl(this.item.state ? this.item.state : '', Validators.required), into this:                 state: new FormControl(this.item.state ? [this.item.state] : '', Validators.required) And now it works! Please add your comment as an anser so I can mark it as right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting an error because `selecteItems`, isn't an array.

In your code

```
this.form = new FormGroup({
                name: new FormControl(this.item.name,Validators.required),
                last_name: new FormControl(this.item.last_name, Validators.required),
                fantasy_name: new FormControl(this.item.fantasy_name, Validators.required),
                real_name: new FormControl(this.item.real_name, Validators.required),
                state: new FormControl(this.item.state ? this.item.state : '', Validators.required),
                city: new FormControl(this.item.city ? this.item.city : '', Validators.required),
                phone: new FormControl(this.item.phone),
                fax: new FormControl(this.item.fax),
                discount: new FormControl(this.item.discount),
                address: new FormControl(this.item.address),
                apartment: new FormControl(this.item.apartment),
                cuit: new FormControl(this.item.cuit, Validators.required),
                email: new FormControl(this.item.email, Validators.required),
                floor: new FormControl(this.item.floor),
                mobile_phone : new FormControl(this.item.mobile_phone)
              });
```

You need to change the `state` definition to:

```
state: new FormControl(this.item.state ? [this.item.state] : '', Validators.required)
```

Setting the item to an array will remove the error and allow you to iterate through using `map`.

Comment: Thanks! That small change fix the issue!

Comment: @Faabass great! glad i could help.